# Shortest inline collection initializer? C#

Tags: c#, initialization

What is the neatest / shortest way I can write an inline collection initializer?

I dont care about reference names, indexes are fine, and the item only needs to be used in the scope of the method.

I think an anonymous type collection would be messier because I would have to keep writing the key name every time.

I've currently got

```
var foo = new Tuple<int, string, bool>[] 
{ 
   new Tuple<int, string, bool>(1, "x", true), 
   new Tuple<int, string, bool>(2, "y", false) 
};
```

Im hoping c# 4.0 will have something ive missed.

Comment: you want the shortest or the neatest?

Comment: If it's much used, you can write your own class that has an `Add(int, string, bool)` method and then use collection initializer, like `var foo = new MyCollection { { 1, "x", true }, { 2, "y", false } };`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The shortest you can get is to use `Tuple.Create` instead of `new Tuple`:

```
var foo = new [] { Tuple.Create(1, "x", true), Tuple.Create(2, "y", false) };
```

Answer (score 5):

a bit less space in there if you use `Tuple.Create(1,"x",true)` instead of the new thing - and you can strip the `new Tuple<tint, string, bool>` stuff before the array too:

```
var foo = new [] { Tuple.Create(1, "x", true), Tuple.Create(2, "y", false) };
```

or take this one:

```
Func<int, string, bool, Tuple<int, string, bool>> T = (i, s, b) => Tuple.Create(i,s,b);
var foo = new [] { T(1, "x", true), T(2, "y", false) };
```

or even

```
Func<int, string, Tuple<int, string, bool>> T = (i, s) => Tuple.Create(i,s,true);
Func<int, string, Tuple<int, string, bool>> F = (i, s) => Tuple.Create(i,s,false);
var foo = new [] { T(1, "x"), F(2, "y") };
```

Comment: btw markdown provides a far easier way to format code *blocks* than what you were doing - just indent each (unescaped) line four spaces! eg see my edit

Comment: oh - thank you - tried the "button" but this will stop on each empty line.... I guess this might get me quicker in the future ;)

Comment: @CKoenig: Select all code you want to format and then press the button. This works.

Comment: BTW: for the OP: F# will get this done without any tricks - (1,"x",true) is there a Tuple<int,string,bool> allready ;)

Comment: Thanks, F# still a bit daunting!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a

```
using MyTuple= System.Tuple<int, string, bool>;
```

at the end of your `using` declarations and then use `MyTuple` instead of the longer version.